# How can I set dynamicly type for state and initialState inReducer with react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have different types of response which I don't know exactly type is ,is that any way to change response type base on dispatch in component

```js
export interface State {
    loading: boolean;
    response: FilteredDataType | Response | string | number,...'I dont know type' ????
    error?: string;
}

export type Actions =
    | { type: 'SET_LOADING '; payload: boolean }
    | { type: 'SET_SUCCESS_SELECTED'; payload: Response }
    | { type: 'SET_SUCCESS'; payload: FilteredDataType }
    | { type: 'SET_FAILURE'; payload: string }




export const initialState: State = {
    loading: false,
    response: ????,
    error: '',

}
export function reducer(prevState: State, action: Actions): State {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_LOADING ':
            return { ...prevState, loading: action.payload }
        case 'SET_SUCCESS':
            return { ...prevState, response: action.payload, loading: false }
        case 'SET_SUCCESS_SELECTED':
            return { ...prevState, response: action.payload, loading: false }
        case 'SET_FAILURE':
            return { ...prevState, loading: false, error: action.payload }
        default:
            return initialState
    }
}

const Selected: React.FunctionComponent<PropsType> = ({ date, from }) => {
  const { state: { session } } = useContext(SessionContext)
  const { selectedSpid } = useInfoState()
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const load = useCallback(async () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_LOADING ', payload: false })
    try {
      if (date && date.length) {
        const response = await getData(date, date)
        const responseApi: DataResponse = response.data
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_SUCCESS_SELECTED', payload: responseApi })
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_LOADING ', payload: true })
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return dispatch({ type: 'SET_FAILURE', payload: e.Tostring() })
    }
  }, [])


  useEffect(() => {
    if (session && selectedSpid) {
      load()
    }
  }, [date, from])
  return (
    <Spin spinning={!selectedSpid}>
      <Row>
      // Map has Error becuse of type
        {state.response && state.response.map((item) =>
          <SelectedCard
            key={item.id}
            {...item}
            icon={true} />
        )}

      </Row>
    </Spin>
  )
}
export default Selected
```

```html
const Selected: React.FunctionComponent<PropsType> = ({ date, from }) => {
  const { state: { session } } = useContext(SessionContext)
  const { selectedSpid } = useInfoState()
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const load = useCallback(async () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_LOADING ', payload: false })
    try {
      if (date && date.length) {
        const response = await getData(date, date)
        const responseApi: DataResponse = response.data
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_SUCCESS_SELECTED', payload: responseApi })
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_LOADING ', payload: true })
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return dispatch({ type: 'SET_FAILURE', payload: e.Tostring() })
    }
  }, [])


  useEffect(() => {
    if (session && selectedSpid) {
      load()
    }
  }, [date, from])
  return (
    <Spin spinning={!selectedSpid}>
      <Row>
      // Map has Error becuse of type
        {state.response && state.response.map((item) =>
          <SelectedCard
            key={item.id}
            {...item}
            icon={true} />
        )}

      </Row>
    </Spin>
  )
}
export default Selected
```

I am going to dispatch type of request base on a different type of request, I am going to know is that any way to change dynamically state base on the request?

is any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code sample, and where you put `I don't know what type`; it sounds like you're trying to have the `State.response` type to be a union type of all possible `payloads` that an action might have. You can do this with a lookup type, as shown below.

```
export interface State {
    loading: boolean;
    response?: Actions["payload"];
    error?: string;
}

export type Actions =
    | { type: 'SET_LOADING '; payload: boolean }
    | { type: 'SET_SUCCESS_SELECTED'; payload: Response }
    | { type: 'SET_SUCCESS'; payload: FilteredDataType }
    | { type: 'SET_FAILURE'; payload: string }

export const initialState: State = {
    loading: false,
}
```

But you also said `...is that any way to change response type base on dispatch in component`. Which sounds a bit like you don't want to have the `Actions` type at all. The actions type cannot be inferred from the usage of `dispatch()` so the only way to do that would be to have your `useReducer` take an `any` type for a second parameter. Then you would lose all the advantages of typescript in your reducer, which I really wouldn't recommend.

Comment: what export const initialState: State = {
    loading: false,
    response: ????
    error: '',

} should be

Comment: actually is not work becuse is will call all types from Payload , which is not right in  {state.response && state.response.map((items, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <Card {...items} />
          </div>
        ))}

Comment: That depends on how you intend to handle the initial state in your application. I would suggest omitting response from your initial state because there is no response when the application first loads. But you could also use null or undefined to represent no response state.

I've updated answer to show what I mean

Answer (score 0):

I mean if you truly have no idea what the response will contain you can just use `any`, or if you know it will be some kind of object you can create a generic object type that will allow it to have anything as a key:

```
type GenericObject = { [key: string]: any }
```

If it's just a certain number of potential types, you could create separate ones and use [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) like you're already doing:

```
type ResponseA = { something: string }
type ResponseB = { somethingElse: string }

...

export interface State {
    loading: boolean;
    response: ResponseA | ResponseB;
    error?: string;
}
```

You can't change the type of something in response to an action that occurs. TypeScript's type checking only occurs at compile time to enforce type safety during development. At runtime, all of the TypeScript is removed and compiled into regular JavaScript that can run in a browser/on a server. As long as the types you're using aren't throwing errors and are enforcing type safety to the level you need,